# NSTimer Not Firing?

Tags: ios, ios7, nstimer

My timer only fires once even though I have repeat initialized as YES. I want my timer to fire every 6 seconds? What is the problem?

```
@interface TCAMyScene (){

    NSTimer *bombTimer;

}

 bombTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] interval:6 target:self selector:@selector(setBomb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[bombTimer fire];
```

Solution:

```
 bombTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6 target:self selector:@selector(setBomb) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Vote to close as an egregious duplicate, plus downvote for not bothering to search before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `NSTimer`:

> You must add the new timer to a run loop, using addTimer:forMode:.
>   Upon firing, the timer sends the message aSelector to target. (If the
>   timer is configured to repeat, there is no need to subsequently re-add
>   the timer to the run loop.)

You're better calling:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

As this will add it to the current run loop in the default mode (which is usually what you want, unless there's an explicit need for a different run loop or mode)

Comment: how do I declare it globally so I terminate the timer in another method the code I posted above gives me an error

Comment: You call it via `[NSTimer scheduledTimer...`, it's a class method. This returns an `NSTimer`, which you can then store in a property on the class for example.

Comment: Thanks got it I was thinking about it all wrong.